# Is there a way to run gzweb in read-only mode?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there.

Is there any way to run gzweb in read-only mode? We are considering to use it for a simulation competition (http://www.robocup-logistics.org/sim-comp), but for visualization only. For this, we'd like to avoid any interference and thus put gzweb into a mode where no modifications are allowed.

Looking briefly through the code I couldn't find much. But it seems the message processing in gzbridge's GazeboInterface.cc might be a place to modify to just ignore change requests, or is there a better/easier way to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16258/is-there-a-way-to-run-gzweb-in-read-only-mode?/) by [timn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3300/timn/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

unfortunately, there is currently no support for read-only mode. You'll probably have to modify `GazeboInterface::ProcessMessages` and disable code that processes certain incoming messages that results in gzbridge publishing to the gazebo server, e.g. light, factory, model, world control, entity delete topics

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1